# how to make inputBox's ok and [Enter] key press make it pop up again with a loop

Tags: vb.net

The main question is: **how can i make InputBox keep poping up when the user either clicks Ok or presses [Enter] on the keyboard?**  This program stores each value in a sequential access file.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click


End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim dblInput As Double

    'Do 
    strInput = InputBox("Enter A Number", "Test Scores Project")
    Double.TryParse(strInput, dblInput)

    outFile = IO.File.CreateText("Scores.txt")

    outFile.WriteLine(dblInput)
    'While user presses the enter button or ok keep asking for more numbers

    outFile.Close()

    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnCount_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCount.Click
    Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader
    Dim strMessage As String
    Dim intFiles As Integer

    If IO.File.Exists("Scores.txt") Then
        inFile = IO.File.OpenText("Scores.txt")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No such file exists", "Text Scores Project")
    End If

    Do Until inFile.Peek = -1
        strMessage = inFile.ReadLine
        intFiles += 1
    Loop

    lblNumber.Text = intFiles.ToString

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I don't even see `inFile` in your code.

Comment: Ill update it so its the whole program.  ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initializing outfile in the declaration:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Using outFile As New IO.StreamWriter("Scores.txt")
        Dim strInput As String
        Dim dblInput As Double

        Do
        strInput = InputBox("Enter A Number(done when finished)", "Test Scores Project")
        If Double.TryParse(strInput, dblInput) Then                
            outFile.WriteLine(dblInput)
        End If
        While strInput <> "done"

    End Using

        Me.Close()
End Sub
```

A simple while loop will work here.

Note: The use of the Using block.  This handles all the clean up of the stream.

Comment: ha nifty! Sorry I didn't mark that as answer right away!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting that warning about `inFile` is because the compiler recognizes that the code path could go through the `Else` branch of `If IO.File.Exists("Scores.txt")` without ever assigning a value to `inFile`.

Try doing this:  `Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader = Nothing`